# Making image url link only with plain text using auto_html Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I put the following text and got an unexpected result using the bundled image filter (AutoHtml::Image).

```
<img src="http://hoge/image.png">
```

That filter translated it into the followging code.

```
<img src=""
<a href="http://hoge/image.png">
  <img src="http://hoge/image.jpg">
</a>
"">
```

I just wanted to transralte only with plain text not with html tag.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`auto_html` gem](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html) is supposed to transform plain text input, not HTML input into HTML. The `AutoHtml::Image` filter simply finds all URLs, such as `"http://hoge/image.png"` and transforms them into an HTML image tag: `<img src="http://hoge/image.png">` (see the last example usage in the gem's [README](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html)). There is no point in applying this filter to a text that already contains HTML tags.

So in your case, perhaps you simply should not use the image filter at all?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I just wanted the HTML code not to be changed.
So I'll change the auto_html gem to another.